# here-api CalculateRoute using Address instead Geo

Tags: here-api

Is there a way call the CalculateRoute API for truck with a source and destination address, instead of source and destination geo.
So, basically, this API with addresses [https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey={apiKey}&mode=fastest;truck&waypoint0=geo!52.534924,13.199499&waypoint1=geo!52.532767,13.198141](https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=%7BapiKey%7D&mode=fastest;truck&waypoint0=geo!52.534924,13.199499&waypoint1=geo!52.532767,13.198141)

Right now, we are doing it using Geo, but the response time is high because we would have to retrieve SourceGeo, DestinationGeo and then CalculateRoute.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways in which waypoints can be specified in calculate route API.

1. geo
2. street reference
3. linkID

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-param-type-waypoint.html

However you can pass address in reverse Geocoder API, get exact waypoints and use it in route API to calculate route,